# Alert Delete: Unable to delete item from flat list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I created a flatlist and a float icon to delete a item from flat list but before it's get delete user will get Alert and on press yes it will b deleted everything is working but after pressing yes item didn't deleted. How can i delete it?
Here is my code

```
state = {
modal: false,
post: [
  {
    key: "1",
    title: "A Good Boi",
    des: "He's a good boi and every one know it.",
    image: require("../assets/dog.jpg"),
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    title: "John Cena",
    des: "As you can see, You can't see me!",
    image: require("../assets/cena.jpg"),
  },
],
image: null,
};

deleteItem = (key) => {
Alert.alert("Delete", "Are You Sure?", [
  {
    text: "Yes",
    onPress: this.setState({
      post: this.state.post.filter((item) => item.key !== key),
    }),
  },
  { text: "no" },
]);
 };
render(){return(
 <FlatList
      data={this.state.post}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <>
          <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={0.7}
            onPress={this.deleteItem}
            style={styles.Delete}
          >
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="delete" color="red" size={30} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

Someone please help,.............................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to pass the item or an index of the item to the function, but I'm not sure of the internals of the `TouchableOpacity` component. The following shows how to pass the item and its key to the `deleteItem` method:

```
deleteItem = (item) => {
  Alert.alert("Delete", "Are You Sure?", [
    {
      text: "Yes",
      onPress: () => this.setState({ // edited
        post: this.state.post.filter((p) => p.key !== item.key),
      }),
    },
    { text: "no" },
  ]);
};

render(){
  return(
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.post}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <>
          <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={0.7}
            onPress={() => this.deleteItem(item)}
            style={styles.Delete}
          >
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="delete" color="red" size={30} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </>
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: it worked thnx but one problem it's deleting item when i click icon and then show alert

Comment: Whoops–answer updated! The `onPress` value must be a function that's called. Previously, it was automatically executing the code every time the button was clicked.

Comment: Worked thnx :)) I'm new with classes. can you help me with another problem?

Comment: I'd love to, but open a new question then link it here. And if this worked, please mark it as the answer. :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141658/image-error-unable-to-post-data-in-home-screen

Comment: here it is please help

Answer (score 0):

In the FlatList
You have to use the prop keyExtractor inside the FlatList. (By doing this you assign a key to every object inside the array)
You also have to pass in the key inside your “deleteItem()” function
Like I have done in the below codes

```
 import React from 'react'
        import {View, Text,StyleSheet, FlatList,TouchableOpacity,Alert} from 'react-native'
        
        
        export default class App extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        this.state = {
          modal: false,
          post: [
            {
              key: "1",
              title: "A Good Boi",
              des: "He's a good boi and every one know it.",
             
            },
            {
              key: "2",
              title: "John Cena",
              des: "As you can see, You can't see me!",
              
            },
          ],
          image: null,
          };
        }
          
          deleteItem = (key) => {
          Alert.alert("Delete", "Are You Sure?", [
            {
              text: "Yes",
              onPress:()=> this.setState({
                post: this.state.post.filter((item) => item.key !== key),
              }),
            },
            { text: "no",
          onPress:()=>null },
          ]);
           };
        
          render(){return(
         <View style={{flex:1}}>
           <FlatList
                data={this.state.post}
                keyExtractor={(item)=> item.key}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={()=>{this.deleteItem(item.key)}}
                  >
                  <View>
                  <Text>`Click here to Delete this =${item.title}`</Text>
 <MaterialCommunityIcons name="delete" color="red" size={30} />
 </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  )}/>
                  </View>
          )}
                }
```